# Spring MVC: How to redirect to a page with error?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to make my Controller to redirect to a page with a custom error message:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@Valid Voter voter, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info("RegisterController encountered form errors ");
            return "registerPage";
        }
        if (service.isVoterRegistered(voter.getVoterID())) {
          logger.info("VoterID exists");

          request.setAttribute("firstName", voter.getFirstName());
          request.setAttribute("lastName", voter.getLastName());
          request.setAttribute("ssn", voter.getSsn());
          return "forward:/question";

        }else {
          logger.info("RegisterController is redirecting because it voter info failed to authenticate");
          //TODO: should re-direct to register page with error

          return "redirect:registerPage";
        }
       }
}
```

```
  <!-- registerPage.jsp -->
    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            Voter Registration
        </h1>
        <div class="span-12 last">  
            <form:form modelAttribute="voter" method="post">
                <fieldset>      
                    <legend>Voter Fields</legend>
                    <p>
                        <form:label for="firstName" path="firstName" cssErrorClass="error">First Name : </form:label></br>
                        <form:input path="firstName" /><form:errors path="firstName"/>
                    </p>
                    <p> 
                        <form:label for="lastName" path="lastName" cssErrorClass="error">Last Name : </form:label> </br>
                        <form:input path="lastName" /> <form:errors path="lastName" />
                    </p>
                    <p> 
                        <form:label for="ssn" path="ssn" cssErrorClass="error">Social Security Number : </form:label> </br>
                        <form:input path="ssn" /> <form:errors path="ssn" />
                    </p>
                    <p> 
                        <input type="submit"/>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form:form>
        </div>
        <hr>    
    </div>
```

On redirecting to register.jsp page, I want the page to display an error message, saying that the voter is not registered. My question is how to get Controller to return to a page as if the form had a validation error (i.e result.hasErrors() == true) .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following section in your jsp--

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty  errors}">
    <div class="error">
    <c:forEach items="${errors}" var="err">
        ${err.defaultMessage}
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>
    </div>
</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Here `c` is nothing but this--

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Also you need to pass the errors into the model and view like this inside the if block in your controller method--

```
model.addAttribute("errors",result.getFieldErrors());
```

`error` class in the **DIV** is nothing but my custom css to display as a red block--

```
.error{
    color: red;
    border:2px solid red;
    padding:10px;

}
```

You can also have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/)

Hope my answer has helped you..

Answer (score 3):

There's something wrong in your controller method. It would be better way to call `getAllErrors()` method from result than the `getFieldErrors()`. Of course if the result is `BindingResult` type . Like this:

`model.addAttribute("errors", result.getAllErrors());`